# Android Application Crashes ActivityManager permission Denied on Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, permissions

My Application is crashing every time when I Run it. only HelloWorld app runs fine.
It says Activity Manager permission denied. Please have a look.

> Console :
>    1.[2016-04-18 17:21:21 - Demo] ActivityManager: open: Permission denied
>   1. [2016-04-18 17:21:21 - Demo] ActivityManager:
>
> Starting: Intent 
>       act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=
>       [android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
>       cmp=com.example.demo/.MainActivity

and here is my LogCat File..
[Android LogCat](http://pastebin.com/Lfd8Ya1c)

And Here is my **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
btn.setOnClickListener(this);

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
tv.setText(et.getText().toString());
}}
```

and Here is my **Manifest File**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.demo"
 android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="14"
android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >

<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />                
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter></intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ui is created in onCreate method of activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
     EditText et;
     Button btm;
     TextView tv;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
          btm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
          tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
          btm.setOnClickListener(this);
     }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         if(v.getId==btm.getId()) tv.setText(et.getText().toString());
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro its solved my problem.. but why does it still says ActivityManager : permission denied

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing your View outside `onCreate()` That is totally  wrong.

Do something like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
     EditText et;
     Button btn;
     TextView tv;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
          btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
          tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
          btm.setOnClickListener(this);
     }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          tv.setText(et.getText().toString());
     }
}
```

Hope this will help you out..

Answer (score 0):

Your initialization is wrong. The view is never created and you are trying to access it. Move the findViewById calls inside onCreate and after the setContentView. Then only you will be able to access the btn object

Answer (score -1):

Do proper initialization of all components. Can not initialize components of view before setting the content view.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
EditText et ;
Button btn ;
TextView tv ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
tv.setText(et.getText().toString());
}}
```

Comment: Please format properly, and explain the differences step by step. Poor answer, otherwise.